# Image is not displayed. Using express.js single page app

Tags: javascript, image, express, path

I have single page app writen in Javascript using Express.js. Everything works well but i have little issue with images. I don't understand why is that happening but it looks like path of the images is incorrect but im 100% it's correct, cuz VSC shows me..

Tbh. This code below is not my work. I found Youtube tutorial how to make single page app in Javascript.

**index.js**

```
import dashboard from './views/dashboard.js';
import posts from './views/posts.js';
import settings from './views/settings.js';
....

const navigateTo = (url) => {
  history.pushState(null, null, url);
  router();
};

const router = async () => {
  const routes = [
    { path: '/', view: dashboard },
    { path: '/posts', view: posts },
    { path: '/settings', view: settings },
    ....
  ];

  //test each route for potential match
  const potentialMatches = routes.map((route) => {
    return {
      route: route,
      isMatch: location.pathname === route.path,
    };
  });

  let match = potentialMatches.find(
    (potentialMatches) => potentialMatches.isMatch
  );

  if (!match) {
    match = {
      route: routes[0],
      isMatch: true,
    };
  }

  const view = new match.route.view();

  document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = await view.getHtml();

  // console.log(match.route.view());
};

window.addEventListener('popstate', router);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.body.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches('[data-link]')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      navigateTo(e.target.href);
    }
  });

  router();
});
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(
  '/static',
  express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'static'))
);

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Server running...'));
```

The menu where i have logo image which is not displayed is something like this. Nothing special under the logo i have clasic links. Do i must somehow import the image like all pages in **index.js**?

```
      <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img
          src="./logo.png"
          alt="Logo" />
      </a>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is located the picture in relation to the html file? In the same folder or somewhere else?

Comment: Same folder as sidebar.js where i use it via IMG SRC